# Apache Nifi with Youtube Data API

Tags: java, ssl, youtube, apache-nifi, truststore

I have used the youtube api URL

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=*****&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&videoId=XhtNooh2gws&maxResults=50

with the Nifi GetHttp Processor, also have set the SSL Context Service to StandardSSLContextService. But it gives me the following error when running the processor

javax.net.SSL.PeerUnverifiedException Hostname googleapis.com does the match the certificate subject provided by the peer

I have setup Java Truststore in my machine and given the path of CACERTS as follows to the StandardSSLContextService in Nifi

/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/security/cacerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be connected with 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1613

created an issue
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3954